# How to create another input range to Meteor event

Tags: javascript, events, meteor

I have this element in my HTML

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
        <input type="range" min="-10" max="100" value="1" step="0.01">
    </div>
```

And my JS

```
  'input input[type="range"]': function(event, template) {
            var sliderVal = $( event.currentTarget ).val();
            Session.set('scaler', sliderVal);
            console.log("Slider: " + sliderVal);
        }
```

I tried to change the class name of my element so I can add another input range slider mapped to a new event but it doesn't seem to work. How to add another one, changing input[type="range"] to scale[type="range"] and amend the element's class name won't work.

Comment: Your question seems to be a bit unclear. Please explain clearly, what exactly you actually want. Are you hinting that you want to add multiple sliders based on the first slider?

Comment: I just want to add another independent slider and a corresponding event.

Comment: Then why not declare it the way you did to the first one? Also, you need a unique id on the sliders to differentiate between multiple sliders.

Comment: I tried but I don't know how to edit the event selector in order to act separately. Do I need to have something like from this input[type="range"]  to this scale[type="range"]   `<div class="slider-wrapper">
        <input id="scale" type="range" min="-1" max="1" value="1" step="0.01">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <input id="offset" type="range" min="-1" max="1" value="1" step="0.01">
    </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Template:**

Each of your sliders is given a unique id. This id is what is going to tell one slider apart from the other.

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
        <input type="range" min="-10" max="100" id="slider1" value="1" step="0.01">
        <input type="range" min="-10" max="100" id="slider2" value="1" step="0.01">
        <input type="range" min="-10" max="100" id="slider3" value="1" step="0.01">
</div>
```

**Event handlers:**

A single event handler that does the job of picking up changes on any of the sliders.

```
// when anything in input[type="range"] changes, 

    'change  input[type="range"]' (event){

            console.log("id of the slider is: ", event.target.id);
            console.log("it's current value is: ", event.target.value);
            // set the id and it's value - which can be used later for whatever you want to do.
            Session.set(event.target.id, event.target.value);
    },
```

`Session.get("slider1")` ==> gets the slider1's current value
`Session.get("slider2")` ==> gets the slider2's current value
`Session.get("slider3")` ==> gets the slider3's current value

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems that I was missing a hashtag to the event selector.

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
        <input id="scale" type="range" min="-1" max="1" value="1" step="0.01">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <input id="offset" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="0.01">
    </div>

'input #scale[type="range"]': function(event, template) {
                var sliderVal = $( event.currentTarget ).val();
                Session.set('scaler', sliderVal);
                console.log("Slider: " + sliderVal);
            },

'input #offset[type="range"]': function(event, template) {
                var sliderVal = $( event.currentTarget ).val();
                Session.set('offset', sliderVal);
                console.log("Slider: " + sliderVal);
            }
```

Comment: Good try, I feel that you don't need to declare an event listener for each slider. One will do the job for many. :)